# GCC failed with flag `-Wl,-no-pie`

Tags: gcc

I'm trying to built a c program using `gcc` with option `-Wl,-no-pie`. It failed with output as following.

```
# gcc -Wl,-no-pie -o test test.cpp 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is `test.cpp` content:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
        printf("hello world");
        return 0;
}
```

Without the option `-Wl,-no-pie`, it works fine.
When I change the option `-Wl,-no-pie` to `-no-pie`, it alse works fine.

gcc version: gcc (GCC) 10.2.0

system: centos 3.10.107 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Why this is happening with `-Wl,-no-pie`, and what's the difference between `-Wl,-no-pie` and `-no-pie`? what else I can try to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason was `ld` version too low (2.23). Updated to `GNU ld version 2.27-41.base.tl2.1`. It works